# Critical sections and the singleton pattern

Tags: c++, multithreading, singleton, critical-section, c++03

Background: One of the problems with using a local static variable in a function as an implementation of the singleton pattern is that if more than one thread calls the function for the first time at the same time, the initialisation of the static variable could be done twice.

My question is, if you wrap the initialisations of the static variables in a critical section, will that prevent the double initialisation from happening? Example:

```
CRITICAL_SECTION cs;

Class get_class_instance() {
    EnterCriticalSection(&cs);

    // is the initialisation of c done inside the critical section?
    static Class c = Class(data);

    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);

    return c;
}
```

Or is the initialisation done magically (not at the point of the declaration/initialisation), like the initialisation of variables member before the beginning of a constructor?

My question is specifically about pre-C++11 since, as per Xeo's answer, C++11 takes care of this by itself.

Comment: With that edit, I should delete my answer, since it's no longer relevant. :P

Comment: @Xeo sorry, I should have been more specific, but I am dealing with a compiler that doesn't support that feature of C++11, I upvoted your answer though, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++11 removes the need for locking. Concurrent execution shall wait if a static local variable is already being initialized.

`§6.7 [stmt.dcl] p4`

> If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion of the initialization.

---

For C++03 we have this:

`§6.7 [stmt.dcl] p4`

> The zero-initialization (8.5) of all local objects with static storage duration (3.7.1) is performed before any other initialization takes place. A local object of POD type (3.9) with static storage duration initialized with constant-expressions is initialized before its block is first entered. An implementation is permitted to perform early initialization of other local objects with static storage duration under the same conditions that an
> implementation is permitted to statically initialize an object with static storage duration in namespace scope (3.6.2). **Otherwise such an object is initialized the first time control passes through its declaration**;

The last part is important, since it applies to your code. When control first enters `get_class_instance()`, it first passes through the initialization of the critical section, then through the declaration of the singleton (as such will initialize it inside the critical section), and then will pass through the deinitialization of the critical section.

So from a theoretical point of view, your code should be safe.

Now, this can be improved though, as to not enter the critical section on every function call. The basic idea of @Chethan is sound, so we'll base it on that. However, we're going to avoid the dynamic allocation too. For that, however, we're relying on Boost.Optional:

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

Class& get_class_instance() {
    static boost::optional<Class> c;
    static bool inited;

    if (!inited){
        EnterCriticalSection(&cs);

        if(!c)
            c = Class(data);

        LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
        inited = true;
    }

    return *c;
}
```

Boost.Optional avoids the default initialization, and the double check avoids entering the critical section on every function call. This version however introduces a call to the copy constructor of `Class` in the assignment. The solution to that are inplace factories:

```
#include <boost/utility/in_place_factory.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

Class& get_class_instance() {
    static boost::optional<Class> c;
    static bool inited;

    if (!inited){
        EnterCriticalSection(&cs);

        if(!c)
            c = boost::in_place(data);

        LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
        inited = true;
    }

    return *c;
}
```

My thanks go to @R. Martinho Fernandes and @Ben Voigt who collaborated to this final solution. If you're interested in the process, feel free to take a look at the [transcript](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2251976#2251976).

---

Now, if your compiler supports some of the C++11 features already, but not the static initialization stuff, you can also use `std::unique_ptr` combined with placement new and a static aligned buffer:

```
#include <memory> // std::unique_ptr
#include <type_traits> // alignment stuff

template<class T>
struct destructor{
    void operator(T* p) const{
    if(p) // don't destruct a null pointer
        p->~T();
    }
};

Class& get_class_instance() {
    typedef std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Class),
        std::alignment_of<Class>::value>::type storage_type;
    static storage_type buf;
    static std::unique_ptr<Class, destructor> p;
    static bool inited;
    
    if (!inited){
        EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
    
        if(!p)
            p.reset(new (&buf[0]) Class(data));
    
        LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
        inited = true;
    }
    
    return *p;
}
```

Comment: Is it also true for a static class member?

Comment: Ah, C++11 to the rescue. What about pre-C++11?

Comment: @Seth: Pre-C++11 doesn't even know about concurrent execution. :P I don't know enough about concurrency to make a comment on your idea though. :(

Comment: @littleadv: p4 deals with initialization of block scope variables. Gimme a sec to look for global locals. (In any case, a global local can be easily transformed into a block scope local by putting it inside a function.)

Comment: If the compiler allows double-initialization, I don't think this will prevent it.  Either you have no effect (if the compiler has a single check covering all static locals) or a possible dead-lock (if the compiler implements one check per local).

Comment: @Ben: The standard specifically states that a local static will be initialized the first time control passes through a declaration. It doesn't matter if the critical section is tried to enter concurrently, all that's important is that the control never reaches the declaration of `instance` concurrently.

Comment: @Xeo: I disagree.  The goal is to make sure `instance` is only initialized once.  I don't see that it matters whether multiple-initialization is serialized or not, it should not be allowed at all.

Comment: @Seth: I hope you didn't see the pointer-and-dynamic-alloc version I quickly changed after the edit. :)

Comment: @Ben: Mind joining me in the Lounge<C++> chatroom? It'll be easier to communicate there.

Comment: @Seth: While I try to think of something, please go through my discussion with Ben [starting here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2251881#2251881).

Comment: @Xeo: Please check the edit I'd made to address the point sbi brought up in chat about the double-checked lock.

Comment: It doesn't work because you never initialized the CRITICAL_SECTION. You need to locklessly change the state.

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping the initialization with critical sections would certainly help! I would use the code below to make sure the our static variable is initialized only once.

```
CRITICAL_SECTION cs;

Class& get_class_instance() {
    static Class *c; //by default, global and static variables are assigned default values. Hence c will be NULL when the program starts.

    EnterCriticalSection(&cs);

    if(c == NULL)
        c = new Class(data);

    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);

    return *c;
}
```

Comment: Oh! Yep. My bad. Lets allocate it on the heap!

Comment: This can be made way prettier without locking on every call. `static char init_forcer = (EnterCriticalSection(&cs), c = new Class(data), LeaveCriticalSection(&cs), 0);` right below the `static Class* c;` line should do the job (not tested).

Comment: @Seth: I don't know if it works, it just *should* in theory. :) Usually though, theory and practice have quite a wide margin between them.

Comment: @Xeo: Don't you need a test inside the critical section?

Comment: @Ben: Why? The code is only executed once when the control first enters the function (since it's used to initialize a static local). As such, on the first execution, `c` is of course still a null pointer.

Comment: @Xeo: Umm, isn't the possibility that two threads hit the initialization simultaneously and both execute the whole point of the exercise?

Comment: @Ben: My answer now contains a better version that should work like I had in mind for my earlier comment. It was indeed wrong to initialize like that.

Comment: @Xeo: continuing comments on your answer instead then

Comment: As I just now noticed, this question leaks resources. When will you `delete instance;`?

Comment: @Xeo - the point of singleton is that you **don't** `delete instance`, its allocated once and forever. If you expect exiting your application and still use singletons - then you put the `delete` code there (at the portion that handles exiting the application, that is).

Comment: @littleadv: I thought the point(s) of a singleton was allowing only a single instance of a class and providing global access to it. If you don't delete it, you're leaking resources. The point of a singleton isn't to leak resources.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes true, but Xeo was referring to the code in the question, what I was trying to say that if at all, the clear-up is to be done elsewhere,

Comment: You never initialized the CRITICAL_SECTION, which makes this a recursive problem.

Answer (score 2):

For C++03, you need to *locklessly* update the state. This is because you cannot use a lock without initializing it, which will run into the exact same problem again recursively, since you need to thread-safe-initialize the lock you're going to use to thread-safe-initialize. Whoops. You can rely on only zero-initialization for globals and some lockless instructions. This is also much faster.

You can solve this problem with a state variable and a lockless CAS instruction.

```
enum State {
    ObjectUninitialized,
    ObjectInitializing,
    ObjectInitialized
};

volatile std::size_t state; // Must be initialized to 0- done by compiler
                            // before main(). All globals are 0
                            // Also must be word sized

T* func() {
    static char buffer[sizeof(T)];
    long result = InterlockedCompareExchange(&state, ObjectInitializing, ObjectUninitialized);
    if (result == ObjectInitialized) {
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(buffer);
    }
    if (result == ObjectInitializing) {
        while (state == ObjectInitializing); // read is atomic for word-size variables
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(buffer); // and use volatile to force compiler to add     
    }
    if (result == ObjectUninitialized) {
        new (buffer) T();
        InterlockedExchange(&state, ObjectInitialized);
        return reinterpret_cast<T*>(buffer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your code specifically is correct, but generally yes, it would solve the problem.